# Issues with Swiftmailer using XAMPP

Tags: xampp, swiftmailer

I have downloaded Swift-mailer using composer, however when I go to test it I keep getting error messages.

This is what I have set up to set with:

```
<?php
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

// Create the Transport
 $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.justbitestreats.com', >25))
->setUsername('XXXXXX')
->setPassword('XXXXXX');

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

// Create a message
$message = (new Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
->setFrom(['julie.mercer@justbitestreats.com' => 'Julie'])
->setTo(['jbtreats@yahoo.com', 'other@domain.org' => 'JBT'])
->setBody('Here is the message itself');

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

I have also tried using sendmail:

```
<?php
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php'(include_path='D:\xampp\php\PEAR');
// Create the Transport
$transport = new Swift_SendmailTransport('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
// Create a message
$message = (new Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
->setFrom(['julie.mercer@justbitestreats.com' => 'Julie'])
->setTo(['jbtreats@yahoo.com' => 'A name'])
->setBody('Here is the message itself');

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

I keep getting the same error messages

Here is the error message:

> Warning: require_once(/path/to/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\JBT-Emails\sendmail.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\JBT-Emails\sendmail.php on line 2

Comment: It seems you're trying to access a file that isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded a package through **composer** in PHP then you should include the autoloader like this-

```
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . './vendor/autoload.php');
```

I noticed in your error that your path is-

> D:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\JBT-Emails\sendmail.php

If you directly include vendor folder in `sendmail.php` then it may not work so you should try to provide a full path like I have mentioned above and it will find the file.

Comment: I believe the vendor folder exists in your JBT-Emails folder. Please confirm.

Comment: ok so this is the path that the vendor file is in:  D:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\JBT-Emails\Swiftmailer\vendor and the autoload.php is in the vendor file along with the test email,  would I still need to add the above code to my test email?

Comment: If your test email php file and autoload.php files are in the same folder then try this - require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . './autoload.php');

Comment: ok, now the error message is :  Warning: Use of undefined constant FILE - assumed 'FILE' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in D:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\JBT-Emails\Swiftmailer\vendor\sendmail.php on line 3

Comment: Ok my answer got autocorrected. Please add two underscores before and after FILE. Like this `__FILE__`

Comment: Thanks, I wrote the file in brackets and I am now getting a URL error,, but I can fix that!  Thank you for all your help!  It appears to be working